# JHipster - JhiAlertService - How to decide how long alerts are displayed?

Tags: jhipster

I have generated a JHipster project with version 4.9.0.

I am using the JhiAlertService to display various messages to users.

I would like to know how to send in parameters to indicate how long the messages are displayed.

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to help us help you.

Answer (score 11):

`JhiAlertService` comes from the [ng-jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster) library.

You can view the code of [alert.service.ts](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/9e2f5832d687d0247d7629c553d80816648b4d8c/src/service/alert.service.ts) to see the available parameters. 
 For customizing the timeout, use the [`addAlert`](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/9e2f5832d687d0247d7629c553d80816648b4d8c/src/service/alert.service.ts#L131) method and pass it a [`JhiAlert`](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/9e2f5832d687d0247d7629c553d80816648b4d8c/src/service/alert.service.ts#L26-L36) object containing a `timeout` parameter:

```
this.alertService.addAlert({type: 'success', msg: 'A short message', timeout: 1000}, []);
```

Note that if you are using the i18n option, the `msg` field is the name of the i18n JSON key, and the `params` field should contain any information that is interpolated into the message.  So for displaying an alert when the "Admin" user is saved successfully, you would use:

```
this.alertService.addAlert({type: 'success', msg: 'userManagement.updated', params: { param: 'admin' }, timeout: 1000}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i was looking for hours on how to make alerts work with internationalization enabed. There is nothing about it on the Jhipster official website or in any Jhipster related books.